# Evaluation of effectual functions giving unexpected results

Tags: effects, idris

Title is fairly self explanatory. Using [this paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/973c/87a8c2709c7325a099fa09bb381c7b531c38.pdf) as a reference, I have been working out how to properly use effects in Idris. Creating effectual functions seems straightforward, but the actual evaluation of the effectual functions is giving me results I do not expect. For context, if I have the following program:

```
h1 : Eff Nat [SYSTEM, RND]
h1 = do srand !time
        pure (fromInteger !(rndInt 0 6))

h2 : Eff Nat [SYSTEM]
h2 = pure (fromInteger !time)

h3 : Eff Nat [RND]
h3 = do srand 123456789
        pure (fromInteger !(rndInt 0 6))

runH : IO ()
runH = do
    x <- run h1            -- <---- This one works fine
    --let x = runPure h1   -- <---- This one does not work  << !!!
    y <- run h2            -- <---- This one works fine
    --let y = runPure h2   -- <---- This one does not work  << !!!
    --z <- run h3          -- <---- This one works fine
    let z = runPure h3     -- <---- This one works fine     << ???

    putStrLn $
      "test 1 : " ++ show x ++ "\n" ++
      "test 2 : " ++ show y ++ "\n" ++
      "test 3 : " ++ show z
```

I would expect to be able to get actual values out of h1, h2, and h3 with `runPure`, but the compiler will only let me do this for h3. Both h1 and h2 will only compile if they are evaluated with `run`. The only real differences I see are a) functions with multiple effects cannot use `runPure` or b) the `SYSTEM` effect cannot use `runPure`. Could anyone explain to me why the code above behaves the way it does?

The full error if I choose the line `let y = runPure h2` over `y <- run h2`:

```
When checking right hand side of runH with 
expected type 
    IO ()
When checking argument env to function Effects.runPure:
Type mismatch between
    Env m [] (Type of [])
and
    Env id [SYSTEM] (Expected type)

Specifically:
Type mismatch between
    []
and
    [SYSTEM]
```